# Sqlite Index usage in iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, database-indexes

I am working on one App that uses very Bulk data, i.e it contains 1 table with 7,00,000 rows.

when I search from this I need to use (indexes), but i am not able to get it and use it in my App.

Can any one tell with simple example in iOS that shows exactly the working of INDEXES.

&Regards

Comment: Provide more information about your table(s) and the queries you are doing. Determining the indexes you need can only be done knowing that information.

Comment: Is your `database.sqlite` file and its schema generated using code or copy from a physical file ? If you can find a .sqlite file in your Xcode project somewhere, then you can use this free software: https://github.com/sqlitebrowser/sqlitebrowser/releases to view the resulting database table structure otherwise, try to look for sql commands in your code like `CREATE TABLE`

Comment: When you create a SQLite table e.g. `CREATE TABLE book (bookID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR ....)` the column bookID is index 0, the column name will be 1 and so on, doing a SQL `SELECT * FROM book` will return results in an array which you use 0 index order however, when you are inserting data using SQL parameter binding on the other hand, e.g. `INSERT INTO table (bookID, name ...) VALUES (?, ?, ...)` the column index starts from 1 instead of 0, so you would do `sql_bind_int(statement, 1, paramBookID);` and `sql_bind_int(statement, 2, paramName);`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not best ans but it can give you lot of information about indexing and search type .
[S4LuceneLibrary](https://github.com/mikekppp/S4LuceneLibrary)